# phpseclib : Display output of SSH command from multiple servers in HTML table

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib, exim

I am trying to build a dashboard to see Exim mail queue stats in one place. I want to open one page and see the mail queue count for several servers.

I am using PHPSecLib to connect and run the command.  So I have a connection file for each server, and then the index.php page that the output of each command needs to display in.

This is my index.php file:

```
<html>
<body>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Web1</th>
    <th scope="col">Web2</th>
    <th scope="col">Web3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php include('web1.php'); ?></th>
    <td><?php include('web2.php'); ?></td>
    <td><?php include('web3.php'); ?></td>
  </tr>
 
</table>

</body>
```

My problem is that only Web1 mail queue count displays.  I am no programmer at all so I am sure there's some easy/obvious thing I am missing here.

Comment: Can you share us those 3 included files?

Comment: I assure you - the connection works.
If I open the files individually it displays the count for the server it connects to.
I just can't seem to pull it into one file to see them all at once.

Comment: Do the three files have the same code (only differ in the value)?

Comment: Are `web2.php` and `web3.php` echoing anything when you run them directly (i.e. not from the file you've shared)?

Comment: Yes. Individually they all return the value they should.
I just cannot get them to all play nicely on the same page.

Comment: did you try `var_dump()` instead of `echo()`?

Comment: Like this?
    var_dump ($web1->exec('exim -bpc'));

Still only displays the first one, unfortunately.
After the connection string, that is the only command that runs in the file.

Comment: Actually, I need to see your files, you can change some important things before you share it here if you are afraid of private confidential things.